# Are there easier ways for filling and finding empty list slots without using two indexes?

Tags: python

```py
    import math

    def my_func(stud, grps=2):
    students_list = [[] for x in range(grps)]
    students_amount = math.ceil(len(stud) / grps)
        
    for x, y in zip(range(0,grps), range(0,students_amount * grps,students_amount)):
        students_list[x].extend(stud[y:y + students_amount])
        
        if (students_amount - len(students_list[x])) > 0:
            students_list[x].extend(['__EMPTY__' for x in range(students_amount - len(students_list[x]))])
            
    return (students_list)
    print(my_func(['Anne', 'Diana', 'Gabriele', 'Hannah', 'Inna', 'Luna', 'Maya', 'Nora'], grps=7))
```

Hi everyone. This is a function, that takes a list with group members and the amount of groups as arguments. The function then calculates an equal number of students per group (rounded up, if it is a fraction number). It returns a new list containing all the groups with it's members first and if needed filling all empty slots with the word `__EMPTY__`.

For example, if the parameter grps = 3, then there will be three nested lists containing the 8 group members (3 slots per group or list) and one `__EMPTY__` element in the last nested list.

My question is, can this be done differently without using two indexes? My function seems complicated and I wanted to find out, if there are easier solutions for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would do it: First create evenly splittable list, then return an evenly chunked list.

```
def my_func(stud, grps=2):
    students_per_grp = math.ceil(len(stud)/grps)
    while len(stud) < students_per_grp * grps:
        stud.append('__EMPTY__')
    return [stud[i:i + students_per_grp] for i in range(0, len(stud), students_per_grp)]
```

#### Edit:

Following @Matiiss suggestion makes it a bit shorter:

```
def my_func(stud, grps=2):
    students_per_grp = math.ceil(len(stud)/grps)
    stud += ['__EMPTY__'] * (students_per_grp * grps - len(stud))
    return [stud[i:i + students_per_grp] for i in range(0, len(stud), students_per_grp)]
```

Comment: you can just do `stud += ['__EMPTY__'] * (students_per_grp * grps - len(stud))` instead of that `while` loop

Comment: Yeah you're right, that's prettier as well.

Comment: important what I noticed, don't put the multiplication in the list itself you kinda need to multiply the list, see my edited comment

Comment: wow, thanks both of you guys :D that's a lot easier